Sewer Copper Vent - big leak when AC turns on
Here in Central NJ, 5 day average has been 75. Bi-level with full attic. First time in 5 years this is happening.
Every time the AC kicks on, OR the kitchen sink runs, a leak runs down the copper(?) sewer vent pipe.
The longer the AC has not been on, the larger amount of water runs down when the AC is turned on. The leak seems to be occurring from the second level. I do not have visual access (open a wall) to the pipe yet on the second level. However, during our kitchen reno, there were 2-4 pin holes (second level) in the pipe after we pulled the walls. If this were the issue, and the holes already there, we would have seen this a while ago. There were no signs of water at all on or around the pipe in the attic upon inspection. Nor any signs of water on the underside of the roof indicating an issue with the flashing.
Furnace is 5' from the copper vent pipe. No insulation wrap.
Is it possible that my sewer vent pipe is clogged? Maybe large debris, birds nest etc....? Or just massive condensate because the last time I was running tests and turned the AC on after an hour + of it being off, a slow light pour out of a pitcher amount of water came down.
What else should I be looking for before I go opening the wall under the sink looking for a loose connection.


it is not common to use copper as vent line

I assume it's copper based on the outer coating. Pictures added to original post.

Just discovered. When running the kitchen sink, which is right above the location and presuming somehow tied in or at least near that same line that the leak is running down, is also causing the same leaking issue. House was built in 63

@Traveler. Using copper for drainage and venting is not common now but used to be.

Found the problem. There was a crack in the vent pipe.

AC has nothing to do with roof vent lines. The condenser (in the AC) has usually a collection pan and a 1/2 inch pvc pipe going downwards to drain the pan.
Your drain might be clogged and the pan is overflowing. –

Though there is 'zero' water collected around the furnace. Additionally, why would turning on the kitchen sink (which is tapped into the vent line) also cause the same type of leak? --- Added picture to OP of lines exposed. --- I assumed the pipe may be clogged and just checked, but looks free of obstruction. -- I'm going to open the wall where the kitchen sink drain line taps into the vent pipe to see if there's anything loose etc there. However, that still doesn't explain(?) why the AC causes the same leak. This brings  me back to thinking the vent pipe, of deeper down is clogged. Thoughts?
